# How to get xxx.yyy.zzz.com to translate into yyy.zzz.com?q=xxx with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, drupal, subdomain

I have a website on fortrabbit with a url of yyy.zzz.com and I need to be able to pass an optional subdomain of xxx as query string so that it translates from xxx.yyy.zzz.com where xxx is the optional subdomain into yyy.zzz.com/index.php?q=xxx

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your subdomain points toward your server, you'll need to do something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.yyy\.zzz\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://yyy.zzz.com/$1?q=%1 [R,L]
```

This is an external redirect. The client will see `http://yyy.zzz.com/asdf?q=xxx` in their address bar if they navigate to `http://xxx.yyy.zzz.com/asdf`.

If you want to let the user see `http://xxx.yyy.zzz.com/asdf` in their address bar, you'll need to use a proxy request with the `[P]` flag.

See [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for more information.